# Passing multiple objects as one parameter

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-xe2

I want to pass multiple objects as one parameter with the smallest effort.

I've got some type

```
TOpenMode = [omNew, omEdit, omBrowse]
```

And a procedure

```
procedure OpenForm(Form: TForm; ANewWindow: boolean = false; 
                   Datasets: TUniDataSet; TableOpenMode: TOpenMode);
```

I want to pass more than one dataset. Can I do that without arrays or creating new objects? How can I make them to be passed in pairs `[UniTable1, TOpenMode], [UniTable2, TOpenMode]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to combine multiple objects in a single compound type is a record:

```
type
  TDataSetAndOpenMode = record
    DataSet: TUniDataSet;
    OpenMode: TOpenMode;
  end;
```

For convenience provide a function to initialise one of these records:

```
function DataSetAndOpenMode(DataSet: TUniDataSet; 
    OpenMode: TOpenMode): TDataSetAndOpenMode;
begin
  Result.DataSet := DataSet;
  Result.OpenMode := OpenMode;
end;
```

Then your `OpenForm` function can receive an open array of such records:

```
procedure OpenForm(Form: TForm; const Datasets: array of TDataSetAndOpenMode;
    NewWindow: Boolean=False);
```

Note that I have put the `NewWindow` parameter at the end. Since it has a default value, that default value is only useful when it appears at the end of the list.

Now, to call the function you can write code like this:

```
OpenForm(Form, [DataSetAndOpenMode(DataSet1, OpenMode1), 
    DataSetAndOpenMode(DataSet2, OpenMode2)]);
```

Comment: Any reason why you use a separate function instead of a record constructor? Just curious.

Comment: @Uwe I don't like using `TDataSetAndOpenMode.Create` syntax. When you read that code it leads you to think that you need to call `Free` on that object. For a record that usually is compiler error so you are protected. But, if you happen to be in the `FreeAndNil` faction, then passing a record to `FreeAndNil` leads to pain. For example look at `TRegEx`. You could use an instance method, perhaps named `Initialise`. But that doesn't allow the function call syntax in the question. Hence a helper function.

Comment: Of course I accept your preferences. You still can make the Initialise a static class function (e.g. TStopWatch.StartNew). I actually prefer those record methods to keep the scope together. It is as often a matter of taste.

Comment: @UweRaabe That approach is very good. I'm quite happy with that style also. I formed my views on this back in the old days before records could have methods. I agree that the scoping benefit you describe is significant.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass multiple pairs as one parameter, I don't see how you can avoid declaring at least a record to define the pair and at least an open array parameter to pass multiple instances of those records as one parameter.

```
type
 TDatasetModePair = record
   DS: TUniDataSet;
   Mode: TOpenMode;
 end;

procedure OpenForm(Form: TForm; ANewWindow: boolean = false; 
               Datasets: array of TDatasetModePair);
```

But you'll probably find that it will be much easier to declare your own array type:

```
type
  TDatasetModePairArray: array of TDatasetModePair;
```

the procedure declaration then becomes:

```
procedure OpenForm(Form: TForm; ANewWindow: boolean = false; 
               Datasets: TDatasetModePairArray);
```

Regardless of that though, there is no way around having to create the array before you can pass it to your function:

```
var
  MyArray: TDatasetModePairArray;
begin
  SetLength(MyArray, 2);
  MyArray[0].DS := SomeDataSet;
  MyArray[0].Mode := omEdit;
  MyArray[1].DS := SomeOtherDataSet;
  MyArray[1].Mode := omBrowse;
```

Comment: One of the main reasons to use open array parameters is to avoid the `SetLength` and call the function as per my example. That said, in modern Delphi you could use `TDatasetModePairArray.Create(DatasetModePair1, DatasetModePair2)`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, I tried that in my poor ol' D5, but the messages view had gone walk-about and I couldn't get the syntax right without the error info :-) So I copped out and went for the SetLength version.